# Refreshing page with onClick event returns page does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a list of posts and when the user clicks on the title he should be navigated to the current post by using the post id as an url. My `Link` does changes the url, but it does not update the page and the user is not redirected so I am trying to hook an onClick event that also refreshes the page, but when I do that the url is no longer the id of the post and I get a 404 that the page does not exist. How can I refresh the page successfully after the user has clicked on the `Link`?

Here is my parent component:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Planets from '../Planets/Planets.jsx';
import Signs from '../Signs/Signs.jsx';
import PlanetaryAspects from '../PlanetaryAspects/PlanetaryAspects.jsx';
import Houses from '../Houses/Houses.jsx';

class BlogCategoriesMenu extends Component {


  render() {
    return(
        <div className="blog-categories-menu">
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="blog-categories-menu__items">
         <NavLink to="/planets" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a"  activeClassName="isActive">Planets</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/signs" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Signs</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/planetary-aspects"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Planetary Aspects</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/houses"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Houses</NavLink>
         <div className="content-container">
         <Route path="/planets" component={Planets}></Route>
         <Route path="/signs" component={Signs}></Route>
         <Route path="/planetary-aspects" component={PlanetaryAspects}></Route>
         <Route path="/houses" component={Houses}></Route>
         </div>
         </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
       </div>

    )
  }
} 

export default BlogCategoriesMenu;
```

Here is component that the user clicks:

```
import React, { Component  }  from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';
import { Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Planets extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        currentPage: 1,
        setCurrentPage: 1,
        postsPerPage: 5,
        loading: false
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            this.setState({...this.state, loading: true});
            const res = await axios.get('https://app-endpoint/');
            this.setState({...this.state, posts: res.data, loading: false});
          };
          fetchPosts();
        }

        reloadPage = () => {
         window.location.reload()
        }

  render() {
    const retrogradesPosts = this.state.posts.filter( (item) => {
        return item.categories === 'retrogrades'
      })

      if(this.state.loading) {
        return <Spinner/>
      }
        return(
            <div className="planet-articles-container">
           <div className="">
          <div className="">
          {retrogradesPosts.map(post => (
          <div key={post._id} className="planet-articles-container__post">
          <img className="planet-articles-container__post-img" src={post.picture} alt="avatar"/>
          <div className="">
          <div className="">
           <h2 className="">{post.date}</h2>
            <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} onClick={this.reloadPage}> <p className="">{post.title}</p></Link>
           <p className="planet-articles-container__post-text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 100) + "..."}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          ))}
            </div>
         </div>
           </div>
        )
  }
} 

export default Planets;
```

and my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home/Home.jsx'
import Error from './components/Error/Error.jsx';
import Blog from './components//Blog//Blog.jsx';
import Post from './components/Post/Post.jsx';

const App = () => {

  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
   <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} exact/>
   <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} exact/>
   <Route component={Error}/>
   </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: in the inspect elements panel, when you inspect the generated `a` tag for the h2, does it provides you a correct url  in the href ??

Comment: Yes and if I click it from the dev tools it leads me to the current Post. Also the url get's changed with the right url but it just doesn't show the component

Comment: I have the app deployed on heroku,I can provide the url if that will help more

Comment: I think you should provide the link. It will be easy to find a solution if we can debug it directly.

Comment: Yes, here is the link: https://astro-ecstatic.herokuapp.com/ you can reproduce the issues by going to the blog page on the navigation and just clicking a title of a item in the planets menu

Comment: You are trying to use `BrowserRouter` in multiple places. For example in file named `BlogCategoriesMenu.jsx` there is a browser router. `BrowserRouter` should be only at top level, which is in your `App.js`. Please remove all other `BrowserRouter` and try.

Comment: Yes that works, but I don't get my components displayed on the blog page when you use the menu, instead they get displayed in a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the BlogCatergoriesMenu rendered using /blog?
If BlogCatergoriesMenu is rendered inside the App and this "App Component" is wrapped by BrowserRouter then remove the BrowserRouter in BlogCatergoriesMenu to make it work.
Your updated BlogCatergoriesMenu will look something like this

```js
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Planets from '../Planets/Planets.jsx';
import Signs from '../Signs/Signs.jsx';
import PlanetaryAspects from '../PlanetaryAspects/PlanetaryAspects.jsx';
import Houses from '../Houses/Houses.jsx';

class BlogCategoriesMenu extends Component {


  render() {
    return(
        <div className="blog-categories-menu">
        <div className="blog-categories-menu__items">
         <NavLink to="/planets" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a"  activeClassName="isActive">Planets</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/signs" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Signs</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/planetary-aspects"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Planetary Aspects</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/houses"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Houses</NavLink>
         <div className="content-container">
         <Route path="/planets" component={Planets}></Route>
         <Route path="/signs" component={Signs}></Route>
         <Route path="/planetary-aspects" component={PlanetaryAspects}></Route>
         <Route path="/houses" component={Houses}></Route>
         </div>
         </div>
       </div>

    )
  }
} 

export default BlogCategoriesMenu;
```